# Searchbar that searches through a json array from the server

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-studio

I am trying to create search bar that searches through json data from a server and presents the results in a ListView. The data is in the form of an array. For Example

```
ProductList: [

{ ProductCode: "10012010",
  ProductName: "Kell", 
  ProductGrammage: "120 gm", 
  ProductBarcode: "890123456789", 
  ProductCatCode: "40", 
  ProductCatName: "Packed Food and Condiments",
  ProductSubCode: "4001", 
  ProductSubCodeName: "Breakfast & Cereals",
  ProductMRP: "120", 
  ProductBBPrice: "115" },

ect...

]
```

So lets say I type in Kell in the search bar. I want this Kell object to pop up in my list view.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the JSON and put the result into an `ArrayList`.
You need an `ArrayAdapter` that implements the `Filterable` interface and set it to the `ListView`.

Your `ArrayAdapter` should look similar to:

```
private class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Code from [here.](https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android)

Comment: Thank you! how should i make an ArrayList with the array i get from my JSON data?